# MacVim json double quotes

Tags: json, vim, config, macvim, double-quotes

I have a fresh install of janus vim plugins and macvim.

For some reason when I open a .json file in macvim, there are no double quotes around the keys or values in the .json file.  As I scroll down the lines of the file, then double quotes show for the key and value of the line I am currently on.

If I open the file in vim, then everything works as expected.

Why is macvim behaving differently from vim?  How can I disable this macvim functionality?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've probablly installed [vim-json](https://github.com/elzr/vim-json) which hides double quotes.

To [disable the concealing of double quotes](https://github.com/elzr/vim-json#user-content-specific-customizations) add `let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 0` to your .vimrc

Comment: Is this the default for macvim, now?  I have been using janus and macvim for years, but I needed to do a fresh install of both and now I notice this issue.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction.  I searched my computer and was not able to find vim-json, however I believe its functionality is somewhere on my computer.  I say this because I was able to adjust my macvim functionality by following the [vim-json instructions](https://github.com/elzr/vim-json#user-content-specific-customizations) to add `let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 0` to my .vimrc. Thanks.

Comment: @user2517182 is using Janus, so this setting should go in the `~/.vimrc.before` file.  This solved my problem, so upvoting :)

Comment: I did not have `vim-json` installed. I tried to add the `conceal = 0` to no avail. It seems MacVim just hides quotes automatically now (`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Feb  6 2016 05:47:51)`). However, after installing `vim-json`, the `conceal = 0` did work for me. That should do for now, though I would like to know how to see quotes in JSON files without installing a plugin. :)

Comment: On macvim Custom Version 7.4 (89) using `:set conceallevel=0` worked for me to show the quotes.